# Set a configuration the first time my app is used

Tags: android

I'm creating my first app and I want to set "initial settings" so when someone installs my app and opens it in their phone, it will do something different the first time (like the apps that ask for a registration/login the first time that are used) and then the first configuration is automatically loader.

How can I do the "initial settings" to display the first time?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sharePreferences option with a boolean type like isTheFirstTimeUsed

```
final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

if (settings.getBoolean("my_first_time", true)) {
    //the app is being launched for first time, do something        
    Log.d("Comments", "First time");

             // first time task do here what you want to do

    // record the fact that the app has been started at least once
    settings.edit().putBoolean("my_first_time", false).commit(); 
}
```

for example...

Answer (score 0):

You could set a boolean in your own Application class (register it in manifest) and save it in preferences. First launch it is "false", you set it to "true".

Why on Application class ? Maybe you want have different launcher activities. So Application class would be a good place to fit it in.